# Learning Ada: Source Code and Newbie "Forum"?

Tags: ada

I've been reading about Ada, which looks like an awesome and mature language. But despite its history and real-world use (and even a pretty good IDE!), it's not very "Internet-popular." So I'm looking for resources now that Google isn't doing much for me anymore. The wikibook has a lot of breadth but was pretty terse and I found it hard to understand. I've checked out the book scene on Amazon, and I'm sure there are a couple good ones, but they are generally older and pretty expensive so I haven't made the plunge yet.

Rosetta Code Ada examples have been helpful, but I'd definitely appreciate something in between that and something big like GNAT.

And if it exists, I'd love a place where I can have some discussions and Q&A that welcomes new Ada programmers. (I'm sure there's probably a comp.lang.ada or something, but ever since I tried asking beginner questions on comp.lang.lisp I tend to be leery of bugging the battle-worn with questions they don't find interesting.)

Anyway I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask in case anyone has recommendations.

Comment: Definitely check out comp.lang.ada (but please don't post using the badly broken Google Groups interface).

Answer (score 6):

Don't go to *Ada Home*; the Ada community would love to bring it up to date but the owner isn't interested.

The [Ada Information Clearinghouse](http://www.adaic.org/), particularly the '[learning materials](http://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/)' section, is a good start. There's similar information in the '[Free on-line books/courses](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming#Free_online_books.2Fcourses)'. I especially liked John English's book (use [this link](http://faculty.cs.wwu.edu/reedyc/AdaResources/bookhtml/contents.htm) instead of the one at AdaIC). Others recommend *Ada Distilled*.

Answer (score 4):

I find that comp.lang.ada is the place to be. Lots of enthusiasts, people with huge experience (even some language designer), but people that don't mind helping newbies too.

There's too an #ada channel in some IRC (perhaps freenode?), that might be a good place for quick Q&A, though I cannot say by personal experience.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there's a very good list of Ada resources on our very own [ada](/questions/tagged/ada) tag wiki, if you click the [learn more link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ada/info).

The nice thing about it is that, through the magic of community moderation, it will never become an embarassing cobweb that nobody can do anything about, unlike some websites I could mention. {*cough* AdaHome *cough*}

The community also has a presence here on SO, so feel free to ask questions here too.

Last I checked comp.lang.ada was a hangout for actual compiler writers and language designers, among other folks. For the most part they are really helpful people, and can be dang handy for arcana. But sometimes for simple questions it can be a bit like asking Robert Goddard or Werner von Braun for tips on making your model rocket fly straighter.

Comment: Thank you--embarrassed to say that I didn't know tags had their own wikis!

Answer (score 3):

comp.lang.ada is a very nice place, and they treat beginners well. I know from experience. Don't be afraid to ask "easy" questions.

For more Ada resources, you could take a look at the [Ada Resources](http://wiki.ada-dk.org/ada_resources) page maintained by [Ada in Denmark](http://ada-dk.org).

It's a mixed collection of old and new. You might find something useful.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I second the recommendation for comp.lang.ada, it is quite newbie-friendly--unless you're a student trying to get the members to do your homework for you.

If you're a [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/) member, there's some Ada groups there.

The [Ada sub-reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/ada) is a site for posting links to news, announcements, questions, and whatnot (I'm the moderator there).

And, self-evidently, here at StackOverflow is a good place for [Ada questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ada) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ada is a language that (undeservedly!) never got enough love, IMO.

Check out http://www.adahome.com/.  It looks embarrassingly out-of-date ... but you might stumble across a useful resource or two in your browsing.

Less old-fashioned (but still probably not very useful), check out the Ada Clearinghouse: http://www.adaic.org/

Frankly, I'm not aware of any significant "Ada community".  I was surprised to see that Ada is still in the "top 20" programming languages on the TIOBE index:

- http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

Comment: DO NOT check out adahome.com. That site is a persistent thorn in the side of the Ada community. The owner refuses to maintain the site or relinquish the domain name, and it does nothing but cause embarrassment.